# Dart | Convert seconds to DateTime without calculate

Tags: flutter, dart

Sometimes we need day, hour, minute, second to countdown, but what we know just second.

For example:

- 1s -> 0day 0hour 0minute 1s
- 10s -> 0day 0hour 0minute 10s
- 100s -> 0day 0hour 1minute 40s

Here is my solution:

```swift
void _test() {
  var diffseconds = 100;

  var seconds = diffseconds % 60;
  var minute = diffseconds ~/ 60 % 60;
  var hour = diffseconds ~/ 60 ~/ 60 % 24;
  var day = diffseconds ~/ 60 ~/ 60 ~/ 24;

  print('day=$day');
  print('hour=$hour');
  print('minute=$minute');
  print('second=$seconds');
}
```

If I can change second to DateTime, I can get day easily with `date.day` and so on and I don't need to calculate anymore.

So I wonder is there any api or simple way to achieve it **without any calculate**.

I wonder better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this functionality is built into Dart but you can somewhat easy add the following extension to `Duration` which are more or less what you are already are doing:

```
extension RestTimeOnDuration on Duration {
  int get inDaysRest => inDays;
  int get inHoursRest => inHours - (inDays * 24);
  int get inMinutesRest => inMinutes - (inHours * 60);
  int get inSecondsRest => inSeconds - (inMinutes * 60);
  int get inMillisecondsRest => inMilliseconds - (inSeconds * 1000);
  int get inMicrosecondsRest => inMicroseconds - (inMilliseconds * 1000);
}

void main() {
  const duration = Duration(seconds: 123);
  print('Days: ${duration.inDaysRest}'); // 0
  print('Hours: ${duration.inHoursRest}'); // 0
  print('Minutes: ${duration.inMinutesRest}'); // 2
  print('Seconds: ${duration.inSecondsRest}'); // 3
  print('Milliseconds: ${duration.inMillisecondsRest}'); // 0
  print('Microseconds: ${duration.inMicrosecondsRest}'); // 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Duration(seconds: seconds)`, it handles values more than 60.

```dart
Duration(seconds: 123) // 2 minutes and 3 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But `const duration = Duration(seconds: 123);`, `print(duration.inMinutes)` is 2, `print(duration.inSeconds)` is 123. How can I get the 3 seconds?